# What's wrong with my scraper?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to scrape the agent_name its contact details by going into page into page.Sometimes this script return me with one entry,sometime different entry unable to figure out the cause.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()


class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "comp"
    allowed_domains = ["iproperty.com.my"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.iproperty.com.my/property/searchresult.aspx?t=S&gpt=AR&st=&ct=&k=&pt=&mp=&xp=&mbr=&xbr=&mbu=&xbu=&lo=&wp=&wv=&wa=&ht=&au=&sby=&ns=1"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('.//*[@id="frmSaveListing"]/ul')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//li[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//li[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            if item['link']:
                if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                    item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                yield scrapy.Request(item['link'],
                                     meta={'item': item},
                                     callback=self.anchor_page)

            items.append(item)

    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//*[@id="main-content3"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/text()').extract()
        yield old_item
```

Comment: Have you looked at how the webpage varies when your code does and doesn't work?

Comment: I have checked the webpage and it changes with new listing but it should pull the data which matches the xml path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you open up the start URL in the browser and refresh the page multiple times - you'll get different search results.

Anyway, your spider needs adjustment since it doesn't extract all the agents from the page:

```
import scrapy
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()


class criticspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "comp"

    allowed_domains = ["iproperty.com.my"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.iproperty.com.my/property/searchresult.aspx?t=S&gpt=AR&st=&ct=&k=&pt=&mp=&xp=&mbr=&xbr=&mbu=&xbu=&lo=&wp=&wv=&wa=&ht=&au=&sby=&ns=1"]


    def parse(self, response):
        agents = response.xpath('//li[@class="search-listing"]//div[@class="article-right"]')
        for agent in agents:
            item = CompItem()
            item['title'] = agent.xpath('.//a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = agent.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(urljoin("http://www.iproperty.com.my", item['link']),
                                 meta={'item': item},
                                 callback=self.anchor_page)


    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//*[@id="main-content3"]//table//table//p/text()').extract()
        yield old_item
```

What I've fixed:

- using `scrapy.Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`
- fixed the XPath expressions that makes it go through all of the agents on the page, follow the links and grab the agent's self-description/promotion

Comment: Hey can you suggest me how to write a rule for parsing through all the pages

Comment: @nik could you please elaborate it into a separate question? Thanks